# Can I Reuse the ASP.NET WebForm's Master Page in ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to reuse my old ASP.NET WebForm Master Page in new ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor application. Is there is any way I can reuse this Master page or I need to recreate this Master Page as razor Layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Master pages and layouts are very different, and not particularly compatible.

Frankly, it shouldn't be very difficult to convert from one to the other, the HTML should remain the same, but you just replace a few pieces with razor code.  even a complex master page should only have a few placeholders.  The only problem is if you are using a code-behind for the master, which you'll have to figure something out for the razor view.

Comment: Ok Thanks. This seems to be very difficult. I have also found this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/09/01/a-webform-view-with-a-razor-layout-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx). But this is also not solving the issue either.

Comment: IMO the whole point of MVC 3 was to get rid of content controls which are old web forms controls still.  They do not belong in MVC.  So that's why they introduced layouts.  MVC 3 got rid of the last web form based control in MVC which is the content placeholder.  So you should not be using any kind of control that is a web control in MVC such as asp:[whatever]..it's just horrible.  We do not want web form stuff in MVC anymore period.  Thank God for MVC 3.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict - certainly, it's discouraged.  But, if you're using the WebForms view engine in MVC3, you can still have webforms controls and code-behinds.  The point I was making was that this is one hard-to port aspect, if someone is using it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for that unfortunately, but you may find the following article interesting:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx

Comment: Ok Thanks. This seems to be very difficult. I have also found this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/09/01/a-webform-view-with-a-razor-layout-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx). But this is also not solving the issue either.

Comment: Yeah, it's not easy.  It sounds bad, but you might want to consider recreate the Master Page in Razor and port your existing Views over.  Depends on your particular situation if this makes sense or not.